# How to parse a date as an argument in xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I would like to parse a date as an argument in a python function but it is not recognized.

For example:

```
def myfunction(cob_ToGet):
    # cob_ToGet is datetime
    print(cob_ToGet.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```

And calling the following from vba:

```
RunPython ("import mypythonfile; mypythonfile.myfunction(cob_ToGet=28.09.2023)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
Sub tester()
    RunPython "import newproject; newproject.myfunction(cob_ToGet='28.09.2023')"
End Sub
```

or just

```
Sub tester()
    RunPython "import newproject; newproject.myfunction('28.09.2023')"
End Sub
```

So in your function;

```
def myfunction(cob_ToGet):
    # cob_ToGet is datetime
    print(cob_ToGet.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```

`cob_ToGet` is a string so strftime will cause an error. Change to strptime

Something like this will return the value to cell 'A1'

```
import xlwings as xw
from datetime import datetime


def myfunction(cob_ToGet):
    # cob_ToGet is datetime
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets['Sheet1']['A1'].value = datetime.strptime(cob_ToGet, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to pass an argument that will be read as datetime from python?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/vba.html#function-arguments-and-return-values) states, its limited.